# Python PLSRegression : obtaining the latent variables scores using loadings

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pls

In `sklearn.cross_decomposition.PLSRegression`, we can obtain the latent variables scores from the `X` array using `x_scores_`.

I would like to extract the loadings to calculate the latent variables scores for a new array `W`. Intuitively, what I whould do is: `scores = W*loadings`  (matrix multiplication). I tried this using either `x_loadings_`, `x_weights_`, and `x_rotations_` as loadings as I could not figure out which array was the good one (there is little info on the sklearn website). I also tried to standardize `W` (subtracting the mean and dividing by the standard deviation of `X`) before multiplying by the loadings. But none of these works (I tried using the `X` array and I cannot obtain the same scores as in the  `x_scores_` array).

Any help with this?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I just had to better understand the `fit()` and `transform()` methods of Sklearn. I need to use `transform(W)` to obtain the latent variables scores of the W array:

1.Fit(): generates learning model parameters from training data

2.Transform(): uses the parameters generated from fit() method to transform a particular dataset